# Moving blogger blog to custom domain without losing Facebook likes count and G+ plusones

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I recently moved my blogspot blog to a custom domain. While everything works just fine, I lost the G+ plusones and Facebook likes for my posts. Same thing with Facebook comments. (I have Facebook comment social plugin on each post of my blog)

The problem lies in the fact that now data:post.url points to http://mydomain.foo/post-link.html instead of http://blah.blogspot.com/post-link.html and when I looked at the template codes for the corresponding widgets, (Like, +1 buttons and Facebook comments) I found data:post.url being used.

My question is, whether there is a way, using blogger template language, to define the post.url the old way?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge,No.

Even I had the same problem while migrating.

Its time to move on now.Its not feasible to have the url of last blog for fb,g+ counters in your new blog in the long run as well for new posts.

Also,if you keep you old G+ counter,all the precious juice of SEO,etc would link to your old blog and not new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover all your pluses and comments of Google+ on your blog. Pluses will take time to re appear by comments can be appeared right away, if you migrated your sub domain to custom domain recently.

The process is;

1. Go to Blogger dashboard > template > Edit HTML
2. Click on **Revert widget templates to default** tab.
3. A window will pop up, check the box of **Blog1** and click on **Revert selected widgets**
4. Now View Blog you can see all your comments have restored.

It is well experienced process, you can use to recover Google plus comments on your blog.

Thanks